# How does a spring batch job know its finished and get notified when launch a job

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on spring batch application now. There is one problem i want to ask how does a spring batch job know its finished?

For example, A spring batch job have one step. when a step finished,
how the job know the step finished. the step send any signal to job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the job that drives the execution of it steps. So it knows about the lifecycle of a step.

Here is an example of the [SimpleJob](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/job/SimpleJob.java#L135) implementation. In this example, the job knows that the step is finished when the `handleStep` method returns.